# Add attributes to Entity Framework database first generated classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 and generating my classes using the database first approach. I have a an EDMX file in my solution.

I am trying to add attributes to my classes using the MetadataTypeAttribute approach which seems to be the recommended way of doing this outside of editing the T4 template, however, I cannot seem to get it to work because I keep getting this compile error:

**'Patient' is an ambiguous reference between 'PatientManagementSystem.Patient' and 'PatientManagementSystem.Models.Patient'**

Here is the code I am using:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(PatientMetadata))]
public partial class Patient
{
}

public class PatientMetadata
{

    [Required]
    public string LastName {get; set;}

}
```

Is this error happening because I don't actually have classes for this because I am doing Database first and everything in the EDMX?

Thanks!
Flea

Comment: What's the namespace for your edmx and for the class above? They should match.

Comment: Adam, the namespace for the EDMX is `empty` (Also, it's in a class library project that is apart of my MVC project) and the namespace for my class is: `PatientManagementSystems.Models`

Comment: Adam, that was the problem. I had to fix the namespaces and now it seems to be working. If you want to copy what you said and put it as the answer I will mark it for you. Thanks!

Comment: thx, added answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure both are in the same namespace. Since it's a partial class, the class you are modifying must also be in the same namespace or it isn't the same class.